# to order object contain dates in html view by angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have to arrange status(P,A) according to date in ascending order but it showing me in same order as they are inserted. but i want to arrange accourding to date.

API Data:-

```
$scope.students{

"name": "sample",
"def": [
    {
        "setId": "arun",
        "Date": [

            {
                "day": "2016-09-28",
                "status": "A"
            },
            {
               "day": "2016-09-27",
                "status": "P"
            },

    {
                "day": "2016-09-29",
                "status": "A"
            },

    {
                "day": "2016-09-26",
                "status": "P"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "deepak",
        "Date": [
             {
                "day": "2016-09-28",
                "status": "P"
            },
            {
               "day": "2016-09-27",
                "status": "A"
            },
    {
                "day": "2016-09-29",
                "status": "A"
            },

    {
                "day": "2016-09-26",
                "status": "P"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

}

html page :-

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>S.No.</td>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>26-9-2016</td>
    <td>27-9-2016</td>
    <td>28-9-2016</td>
    <td>29-9-2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-ng-repeat="student in students" st-select-row="row">
        <td data-ng-bind="$index+1"></td>
        <td data-ng-bind="student.name"></td>
        <td data-ng-repeat="data in student.Date" data-ng-bind="data.status"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

want to show on screen in this way:

```
 1. Name   | 26-9-2016 | 27-9-2016 | 28-9-2016 | 29-9-2016|
 2. Arun   | P         | P         | A         | A        |
 3. dDepak | P         | A         | P         | A        |
```

but i am getting in this way on screen :

```
  1. Name   | 26-9-2016 | 27-9-2016 | 28-9-2016 | 29-9-2016|
  2. Arun   | A         | P         | A         | p        |
  3. Deepak | P         | A         | A         | P        |
```

Comment: did you check the working demo in the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ng'])
  .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

      $scope.students = {

        "name": "sample",
        "def": [{
          "name": "arun",
          "Date": [

            {
              "day": "2016-09-28",
              "status": "A"
            }, {
              "day": "2016-09-27",
              "status": "P"
            },

            {
              "day": "2016-09-29",
              "status": "A"
            },

            {
              "day": "2016-09-26",
              "status": "P"
            }
          ]
        }, {
          "name": "deepak",
          "Date": [{
              "day": "2016-09-28",
              "status": "P"
            }, {
              "day": "2016-09-27",
              "status": "A"
            }, {
              "day": "2016-09-29",
              "status": "A"
            },

            {
              "day": "2016-09-26",
              "status": "P"
            },
          ]
        }]
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">

   <table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>S.No.</td>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>26-9-2016</td>
    <td>27-9-2016</td>
    <td>28-9-2016</td>
    <td>29-9-2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-ng-repeat="student in students.def" st-select-row="row">
        <td data-ng-bind="$index+1"></td>
        <td data-ng-bind="student.name"></td>
        <td data-ng-repeat="data in student.Date | orderBy :'day'" data-ng-bind="data.status"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

The Json data has some keys with wrong names so from your question made a bit assumption and did  changes in your  HTML part.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="student in students.def" st-select-row="row">
        <td data-ng-bind="$index+1"></td>
        <td data-ng-bind="student.name"></td>
        <td data-ng-repeat="data in student.Date | orderBy :'day'" data-ng-bind="data.status"></td>
  </tr>
```

Just use `orderBy` and provide the key to perform ordering in your case `'day'`

Comment: day is in 'string' format to use orderBy- 'day' you have to first convert it into date format. but after converting also it is not giving correct output. i had use orederBy and filter.

Comment: check the code snippet , its working fine.Updated the answer